# Zebra FX7500. Using HTTP POST to send data from reader to url

Tags: tags, http-post, rfid, reader

I bought a zebra FX 7500 fixed rfid reader. I have connected it to my work laptop. I want to transfer the read data of the tags from the reader to a web application hosted on my localhost. The application is hosted on `http://127.0.0.1:8000` using a django server. How can I POST data to a specific URL of my web app with this configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You could:

1. Upgrade to the latest firmware ([3.10.30.0])[1](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/operating-system/fx7500-series-operating-system.html) which is free and use the IoT Connector service to use the HTTP POST method to send the tag data.
2. Buy a license for the FX7500 service "FX Connect" to use the HTTP POST method to send the tag data.

Both are done in the web GUI of the reader.

Answer (score 1):

The FX7500 SDK is here: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/fx7500-series-sdk.html and supports applications in both C & Java.  You would need to write an application in one of those two lanaguages to post the received data to your web app.